# If div with ID A has class B, add a class X to div with ID Y

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm really new to this so bear with me

I have this:

```
<div id="A" class="B"></div>
<div id="Y"></div>
```

I need this:

if div `#A` has class `.B`, add class `.Z` to div `#Y`

I realise it's a basic script but i can't figure it out.
Please help :)

Thank you

Comment: `if($('#A').hasClass('B')){$('#Y').addClass('Z')}`

Comment: I'd suggest you at least scan read through the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com). Even if you don't read it fully, just knowing the method names gives you an good idea of what can be done and how.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

    if ( $("#A").hasClass("B") ){
      $("#Y").addClass("Z") 
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple if you take a look at the jquery docs.
As you described it correctly:

```
if($('#A').hasClass('B')) {
  $('#Y').addClass('Z')
}
```

[jQuery's hasClass doc](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)
and
[jQuery's addClass doc](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasClass()` to check class is exists on element and then use `addClass()` to add class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 if($("#A").hasClass("B"))
        {
      $("#Y").addClass("Z")
        }
        console.log($("#Y").attr("class"))
});
```

```html
<div id="A" class="B">A</div>
<div id="Y">Y<Y/div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```